# How to represent this basic expression?

Tags: java, c++, c

I know basically how post increment and pre-increment work. But I'm just wondering in any language if `++i` expression is represented as `i = i+1;` then how to represent `i++;`

Comment: it's the same, just the execution time is another?

Comment: I can't comment on all languages, but in C and C++ there's no other expression with the same effect and value as post-increment. I suspect Java's the same.

Comment: @kylecorver: No, the two expressions have the same side effect but different values. `i++` is an *rvalue* holding a copy of value of `i` before the increment. `++i` and `i=i+1` are both *lvalues* denoting the variable `i` after the increment.

Comment: for i++ there is a copy that is done previouly to the incrementation and you use this copy in your expression. That's why ++i is more encourage for iterator as there is no extra copy.

Comment: @NGI is it so? Interesting, never knew this. You have any reference for this which I can refer? I thought modern compilers would have optimized this anyway...

Comment: This is a good ? I don't know why people start down voting for no reason.

Comment: @NatashaDutta: "I thought modern compilers would have optimized this anyway.." - they do, in most situations. But with pre-increment, there's no need to worry about whether they do or not.

Comment: @NatashaDutta, for the basic mechanism I would refer to Scott Meyers  More Effective C++ item 6 "Distinguish between prefix and postfix forms of increment and decrement operators ".I think the copy may not be eluded/avoided "by definition".

Comment: @MikeSeymour: In C, `++i` and `i = i + 1` are both rvalues.  This is in contrast to C++.

Comment: @caf: Good point, and yet another example of why questions should be about a single language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C or C++,

`++i` means

```
(i = i + 1)
```

`i++` means

```
(i = i + 1, i - 1)
```

Comment: please add the properties of comma operator in last case, otherwise, it may be a bit confusing to newcomers. :-)

Comment: For the case of C++ you probably have to add a disclaimer like *", unless some yahoo has overloaded one or more of the relevant operators for the type of `i`"*.

Comment: @NatashaDutta @saka1029  `(i = i + 1, i - 1)` what will be the value of `i` after this line and why

Comment: Expressions sparated by comma operator `(e1, e2, ... , en)` are evaluated  left to right sequencially.  and the last expression `en` is returned.

Comment: I thinks it's a bit more complicated when i is an object (like iterators). Which will involve copying the object in the second case.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of how the value of i gets changed, they're the same thing - So they're both equivalent to i = i + 1;

The difference only becomes apparent when they're used as part of an expression.

```
j = i++;    // j = i

j = ++i;    // j = i + 1
```

Comment: heh???? `i = i++;` is ___UB__. don't use it. Read bout sequence points.

Comment: Why was there a downvote on this answer? If there's an issue with it I'd like to correct it.

Comment: @Natasha I know i = i++ is not something that is ever correct, I was just presenting it as an interesting side-effect to educate and amuse! Sounds like I should remove it though.

Comment: Sorry Natasha, didn't mean to imply that you had... I was replying to your comment seperately. No offence meant or taken.

Comment: yeah, same here. Hope you got my point why i asked you __not__ to use `i = i++`, right?

Comment: Absolutely! It's a crazy thing to do! I was only pointing it out as a curiosity that's all. It does something different to what a beginner would expect, and I have seen it done accidentally by beginnners in the past. Incidentally, what does _UB mean?